# Вывод всех значений вектора, возвращённого через std::future

Tags: c++, циклы, c++11, vector

```
auto t1 = async(thr, q);
vector<Employee> a = t1.get();
for (auto ? : t1.get()) // вот тут трабл
cout << a[i].name << endl;
```

Необходимо в цикле вывести все значения вектора. Как правильно обращаться с каждому из его элементов в цикле (вопросительный знак в строке 3)?

Answer (score 3):

1. `vector<Employee> a = t1.get();`

   Как я понял, вы тут получаете результат и пытаетесь сделать это снова в 3-й строке. Думаю, что это, как минимум, странно. Хотя, скорее всего, это ошибка.
2. `for (auto ? : t1.get())`

   Скорее всего, нужно так:

   ```
   auto t1 = async(thr, q);
   vector<Employee> a = t1.get();

   for (const auto& item: a) {
       cout << item.name << endl;
   }
   ```